# How to pad all lines with spaces to a fixed width in Vim (perhaps using sed, awk, etc.)?

Tags: vim, sed, awk

How can I pad each line of a file to a certain width (say, 63 characters), padding with spaces if need be?

For simplicity, let’s assume that all lines are guaranteed to be less than 63 characters.

I use Vim and would prefer a way to do it there, where I can select the lines I wish to apply the padding to, and run some sort of a `printf %63s current_line` command.

However, I’m certainly open to using sed, awk, or some sort of linux tool to do the job too.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Vim

```
:%s/.*/\=printf('%-63s', submatch(0))
```

Comment: fantastic, thankyou! I didn't realise you could use `printf` within the replacement field in vim, I'll have to read up.

Comment: the `.63` precision is not necessary here.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee:  Note, though, that this command does not work correctly for a multibyte encoding (like UTF-8), since `printf()` counts string width in bytes.  I would recommend an [alternative solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9407042/254635).

Answer (score 29):

```sh
$ awk '{printf "%-63s\n", $0}' testfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 15):

In Vim, I would use the following command:

```
:%s/$/\=repeat(' ',64-virtcol('$'))
```

The use of the `virtcol()` function here, as opposed to the `col()` one,
is guided by the necessity to properly handle tab characters as well as
multibyte non-ASCII characters that might occur in the text.)

---

To compute the length of the longest line in the buffer (plus 1) —
to be used in place of 64 — one can use the following command:

```
:let m = max(map(range(1, line('$')), 'virtcol([v:val,"$"])'))
```

The range of lines can be narrowed, if necessary. For example, to
do the same for the visually selected lines, one can provide `map()`
with the `range(line("'<"), line("'>"))` argument, instead (see
`:help line()`, `:help '<`). (Notice that in the latter case, to
run the command interactively while in Visual mode, one will need
to delete the `'<,'>` prefix that Vim will automatically put in the
command line once `:` is typed.)

To do both steps in a single command invocation, one can join the two
commands with `|`. For instance, to pad visually selected lines
(or the lines that were in the last Visual selection), run:

```
:let m=max(map(range(line("'<"),line("'>")),'virtcol([v:val,"$"])')) | '<,'>s/$/\=repeat(' ',m-virtcol('$'))
```

If used frequently, this combined command can can be bound to a key mapping.
Here is an example implementation of a Visual-mode key mapping to be added
to the `.vimrc` file:

```
vnoremap <silent> <leader><bar> :call RightPadLines(' ', +0)<cr>
func! RightPadLines(char, extra) range
    let m = max(map(range(a:firstline, a:lastline), 'virtcol([v:val, "$"])'))
    let m += a:extra
    sil exec $'{a:firstline},{a:lastline}' 's/$/\=repeat(a:char, m-virtcol("$"))'
endfunc
```

The keyboard shortcut here is the leader key (see `:help mapleader`) followed
by the `|` key, but, of course, any combination can be used instead.

Comment: How can it be used to add spaces after the longest line of a selection, in order to create a square block of text and padding the longest line +3 characters par example. In other words, instead of 64 in this example, to use "the max_line_lenght + 3"?

Comment: @ThanasisN: You’ll need to precompute the length of the longest line in the range and use that instead of 64. To do so, for a selected range of lines, first run `:let m = max(map(range(line("'<"), line("'>")), 'virtcol([v:val,"$"])'))` (use Ctrl+U to delete the `'<,'>` prefix that Vim will put in the command line when Visual mode is active), then run `:'<,'>s/$/\=repeat(' ',m-virtcol('$')+3)`. If you wish, you can do that in a single command invocation: `:let m = max(map(range(line("'<"), line("'>")), 'virtcol([v:val,"$"])')) | '<,'>s/$/\=repeat(' ',m-virtcol('$')+3)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know how to combine everything. It works perfectly! How can bind it to a key to run for a selection of text?

Comment: @ThanasisN: You’re welcome! :–) I updated the answer to include an example implementation of a Visual-mode key mapping for triggering the combined command.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```sh
$ sed -i ':a;/.\{63\}/!{s/$/ /;ba}' file
```

or perhaps more efficient but less elegant:

```sh
$ sed -i '1{x;:a;/.\{63\}/!{s/^/ /;ba};x};/\(.\{63\}\).*/b;G;s//\1/;y/\n/ /' file
```

Comment: Hum, the loop it not necessary.

Comment: @jfgagne true but transparent.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, a Perl version:

```sh
$ perl -lpe '$_ .= " " x (63 - length $_)'
```

Answer (score 2):

With sed, without a loop:

```sh
$ sed -i '/.\{63\}/!{s/$/                                                                /;s/^\(.\{63\}\).*/\1/}' file
```

Be sure to have enough spaces in the 1st substitution to match the number of space you want to add.

Answer (score 2):

Another Perl solution:

```sh
$ perl -lne 'printf "%-63s\n", $_' file
```

Comment: I like this, I can add a `# current date` at the end of my varying width crontab lines so I can clean up old jobs.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are comfortable using vim, but here is a pure Bash/simple-sed solution in case you need to do it from the command line (note the 63 spaces in the sed substitution):

```sh
$ sed 's/$/                                                               /' yourFile.txt |cut -c 1-63
```