# How can I add a character at a specific column at the end of every line in Vim?

Tags: vim

How can I add a backslash  marker at a specific column at the end of every line in Vim?

For example, I'd like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Ut nec orci sagittis, pharetra ex ut, 
aliquet nisi.
```

to become

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,            \
consectetur adipiscing elit.           \
Ut nec orci sagittis, pharetra ex ut,  \
aliquet nisi.                          \
```

In this example the backslashes were inserted at column 40.
I know how to insert them at the end of every line (`%s/$/\\/g`), but don't know how to insert the necessary whitespace so that the 
markers be aligned.

Thanks for any help

Comment: workaround (non-vim): https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981695/714112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to do so is to enable [`'virtualedit'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27virtualedit%27), at least temporarily, so you can navigate to a column past the end of your line.

```
:set virtualedit=all
```

Once you're in the correct column, you can use Ctrl+V to enter [blockwise visual mode](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#blockwise-operators) and select this column on every line.

For this particular example, with 4 lines of text, adding a backslash on column 40, you can use this sequence: `40|` (go to column 40, while still on the first line), `<C-V>` (enter visual block mode), `3j` (move down 3 lines.)

At this point, you can use `r\` to "replace" the character under the cursor with a backslash. (There isn't really a character under the cursor, but `'virtualedit'` will do the correct magic to add enough spaces to get to this column and get your backslashes in place.)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. It only changes the lines that are long enough beforehand. If I can get this to work it will be great for putting `# currentdate` at the end of each line in my crontab so I can keep my cron list clean.